Flexmailer define not found by MailingJob.php
We have just done a major upgrade from 5.17.3 to 5.77.1 on our community site.  Most things went well.
I am however having a problem sending out a mailing.  We get the same errors when we schedule the whole mailing, to what I do just selecting "Send Test" and then looking in the log.
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'CIVICRM_FLEXMAILER_HACK_DELIVER' not found in /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Resolver.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Resolver.php(118): Civi\\Core\\Resolver->get()
#1 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(175): Civi\\Core\\Resolver->call()
#2 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Mailing.php(735): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs()
#3 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_mailing_send_test()
#4 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(153): Civi\\API\\Provider\\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke()
#5 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(79): Civi\\API\\Kernel->runRequest()
#6 /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Subscriber/ChainSubscriber.php(205 in /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Resolver.php on line 100, referer: https://<site name>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F

civicrm/civicrm/ext/flexmailer is present and pristine (from 5.77.1 sources), and the site shows the extension as loaded in Administer => System Settings => Extensions
Trying some hackery, and adding this to the top of MailingJob.php
if (!defined('CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS')) {
define('CIVICRM_FLEXMAILER_HACK_DELIVER', '\Civi\FlexMailer\FlexMailer::createAndRun');
}

and now I get 30 seconds of spam such as this in the log, and no mail (LockManager kicks in 'PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded'):
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class '\\Civi\\FlexMailer\\FlexMailer' not found in /mnt/sdb/www/<site name>/epc/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Resolver.php on line 119, referer: https://<site name>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F

All signs point to the extension not being added to Civi's namepsaces - but I don't know where to go from here.
(Non-mailing mail is sending fine from the site)

Do you also have flexmailer installed as a normal extension?  If so, remove it.

I don't think so.  The only files matching flexmailer* are in civicrm/civicrm/ext which matches https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/tree/5.77/ext/flexmailer
I had seen that the standalone plugin was retired, but I presume that this plugin from Github is ok?
